# boolean methods in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
# As a user, you can initialize the guessing game with a number, which is 
the correct guess
# so the initialize method takes in one parameter, and sets game_complete? 
to false
# 
# As a user, I can guess the number, which will 
# return :too_high if its > answer
# return :too_low if its < answer
# return :correct if its = answer
# correct changes the game_complete? to true
# if a user guesses the incorrect number after guessing the correct number, 
it should
# change the game_complete? to false
# return :too_high or :too_low
require_relative 'guess'
describe GuessingGame do 
let(:game) { GuessingGame.new(50) }
describe "#initialize" do
it "expects a single parameter" do
  expect(GuessingGame.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to eq 1
  end
end
describe "#guess" do
it "expects a single parameter" do
  expect(GuessingGame.instance_method(:guess).arity).to eq 1
end

it "returns :too_low when the guess is lower than the answer" do
  expect(game.guess(1)).to eq :too_low
end

it "returns :too_high when the guess is higher than the answer" do
  expect(game.guess(100)).to eq :too_high
end

it "returns :correct when the guess matches answer" do
  expect(game.guess(50)).to eq :correct
end

it "changes game_complete? when the correct guess is made" do
  expect {
    game.guess(50)
    }.to change(game, :game_complete?).from(false).to(true)
end

it "doesn't change game_complete? when an incorrect guess is made" do
  expect {
    game.guess(10)
    }.to_not change(game, :game_complete?).from(false)
end

it "returns :game_solved once you try to guess in a completed game" do
  game.guess(50)
  expect(game.guess(100)).to eq :game_solved
  end
 end

describe "#game_complete?" do
it "returns false in a new game" do
  expect(game.game_complete?).to eq false
end
  end
end
```

Now when I run this code I get the error  GuessingGame#guess returns :game_solved once you try to guess in a completed game

this is  my guess class

```
class GuessingGame
    def initialize(num)
       @num=num
       def game_complete?
            return false
       end
    end
    def guess(num1)
        if num1<@num
            return :too_low
       elsif num1>@num
           return :too_high
       else
          def game_complete?
                return true
          end
          return :correct
       end
end
```

end

I tried to initialise a bool variable with false and once a correct guess is made i made it to true and if that variable is true I return :game_completed but didnt work for me

Comment: This is not initializing variables. This is defining methods. Totally different. Which tutorial/course are you following?

Comment: Its not an online course.Its a institutes training course

Comment: If they teach you this, you should find another institute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't initializing the subject, unless there is more code that you are not showing. Here is a version that works:

```
class GuessingGame

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def guess(num)
    if num < @num
      return :too_low
    elsif num > @num
      return :too_high
    else
      return :correct
    end
  end

end

require 'spec_helper'
require 'foo'

describe GuessingGame do
  let(:foo) { GuessingGame.new(50) }

  describe "when guess is too low" do
    it "returns :too_low" do
      expect(foo.guess(25)).to eq :too_low
    end
  end

  describe "when guess is too high" do
    it "returns :too_high" do
      expect(foo.guess(75)).to eq :too_high
    end
  end

  describe "when guess is correct" do
    it "returns :correct" do
      expect(foo.guess(50)).to eq :correct
    end
  end

end
```

Now some refactoring. It's generally not a good idea to return from the middle of a method. Ruby always returns the value of the last expression, so we can take advantage of that.

```
  def guess(num)
    case num <=> @num
    when -1
      :too_low
    when 1
      :too_high
    else
      :correct
    end
  end
```

The `<=>` operator compares two values and returns -1, 0 or 1. With a little sneakiness we can further refactor the `guess` method to one line:

```
  def guess(num)
    [:correct, :too_high, :too_low][num <=> @num]
  end
```

EDIT

It seems you also want to define another method to indicate whether the game is complete. Here's one way to do that:

```
class GuessingGame

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def compare(num)
    [:correct, :too_high, :too_low][num <=> @num]
  end

  def guess(num)
    @comparison = compare(num)
  end

  def game_complete?
    @comparison == :correct
  end

end
```

Comment: have my +1 for the sneakiness :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this, instead of defining methods just make them into a variable.

```
class GuessingGame
  attr_reader :game_complete
  def initialize(num)
     @num=num
  end

  def guess(num1)
     if num1<@num
          return :too_low
     elsif num1>@num
         return :too_high
     else
        @game_complete = true
     end
     return :correct
  end
end
```

Now to check if the game is done, you can use `game.game_complete` which will return `nil` if it's not complete (which evaluates to false), or if it's compelte it'll return `true`.
Hope this helps you.